# Метод бесключевого чтения RSA

Tags: криптография, rsa

Ребят подскажите пожалуйста, где можно получить информацию о  **Методе Бесключевого Доступа RSA**! (подробно)

Comment: Вас интересуют основы или вы хотите углубленно изучить RSA?

Comment: Если интересует популярное объяснение, почитайте Сингха. Подробнее — Википедию.

Comment: мне просто дали такую тему, мне нужно написать отчет в 15 страниц, ищу об этом методе в интернете не могу найти(((

Comment: Если вы не профессиональный математик или не профессионал-криптограф, у вас вряд ли получится нарыть даже на 5 страниц. разве что с большими междустрочными интервалами)

Comment: Вот вам пример реферата. Даже на три страницы еле тянет, где там 15! https://studfile.net/preview/2983620/

Comment: Или вот еще пример, немного объемнее: https://studfile.net/preview/8570244/

Comment: ой спасибо, а вообще где могу инфу именно про бесключевое чтение получить

Comment: Ну вот, например, тут отрывочек есть: https://studfile.net/preview/5862973/page:6/ И тут https://vikidalka.ru/1-144224.html

Comment: А вообще найти несложно, забей в яндекс "бесключевое чтение rsa" и найдешь много интересного.